# Magento 1.9 Some Products not showing in a category

Tags: magento-1.9

Hello I am struggling with my **category** and **search pages**.

If you look at this image:

[image: Category]

There should be 4 products in each row.

Comment: This issue happens in the search page or even in the category page ?

Comment: It's happening in my category page and when I search for products. I was hoping I could find the issue, and maybe just style over it with css or something

Comment: ok, and the other products will display well on the next page, I mean there is no lack of product, it's just the layout ?

Comment: It is just the layout on category pages and search page. On my frontpage the products display normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to give you a answer, there is two possibilies:

1. Maybe there is some theme config in admin panel to set the display and layout products position,quantity, etc... so you have to check that.
2. You may have some column, div, issue in your category, search template, so take a look to these paths bellow, take a look also in your css.

**category path:**

```
app/design/frontend/{yourPackage}/{yourTheme}/template/catalog/category/view.phtml
```

**search path :**

```
app/design/frontend/{yourPackage}/{yourTheme}/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml
```

Don't forget to clean the cache.